# What is actually meaning of VAR(X1) - VAR(X2)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I have seen this formula **VAR(X1) - VAR(X2) = VAR(X1)/n1 + VAR(X2)/n2**

E.g. We have data for sample1 as [10,14,20,24,28,30,30] and sample2 as [12,12,14,18,22,25,30]

Should I assume substracting VAR of X2 from X1 is equal to **Set minus operation**? Which will result as [10,20,24,28] or it is equal to **Set intersection operation** [10,12,12,14,14,18,20,22,24,25,28,30,30,30]?

After getting the resulting sample, finding **VAR(resultSet)** is equal to **VAR(X1)/n1 + VAR(X2)/n2** ?

Comment: I suspect that the formula you are referring to is actually something like $\mathbb{Var}(\bar{X}_1-\bar{X}_2) = \frac{\mathbb{Var}(X_1)}{n_1} + \frac{\mathbb{Var}(X_2)}{n_2}$.  Does that look like it?

Comment: @Ben Yes yes, I am talking about the same!

Comment: Please have a look at using [latex maths](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) to make your post clearer.